# How to insert data in a batch?

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

In MySQL, I could fire off these statements to insert 5 rows in one shot:

```
CREATE TABLE t (id int primary key auto_increment)
INSERT INTO t VALUES (DEFAULT),(DEFAULT),(DEFAULT),(DEFAULT),(DEFAULT)
```

How can I do the same thing in MS SQL Server?

P.S.  The reason that the suggested duplicate doesn't solve the problem is that it has tables with non-identity columns.  My Table only has an identity column.

Comment: If you are using SQL Server 2008 or later, your question will work.  For 2005 and earlier, you have to get more creative.  In any case, this question is a dupe.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It doesn't work.  I just tried.  If you can make it work, show me how.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Specifically the error is `An explicit value for the identity column in table 't' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.`

Comment: You still never told us what version of SQL Server you are using.  Really bad form IMO.

Comment: You could try turning off the auto increment, but then you would lose the functionality of SQL Server keeping track of the `id`.  Maybe you should consider a change to your schema.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I've tried it in SQL 2005 and 2014 - it worked in neither.

Comment: Could you use a loop along with a stored procedure here?  Or maybe just add a second non auto increment column.

Answer (score 3):

If you have this definition:

```
CREATE TABLE t (id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY)
```

Then you can do this:

```
INSERT t DEFAULT VALUES
INSERT t DEFAULT VALUES
INSERT t DEFAULT VALUES
INSERT t DEFAULT VALUES
INSERT t DEFAULT VALUES
```

Comment: I am trying to do it in a batch operation.  E.g. 5 rows with a single insert.  Like I did it on MySQL.

Comment: @AngryHacker I don't think SQL Server allows that when trying to insert _only_ into auto-incremented column. If you had other columns, you could use MySQL-style syntax.